# Does a "how to debug CSS" reference question exist?

Tags: discussion, support

I encounter many questions where the OP is having trouble getting a CSS style sheet included, and is completely clueless as to how to debug the issue. Often, the only way they know to tell whether a style sheet gets loaded is that the rules are being applied.

Does anybody know of a  reference question that covers (ideally with picshurz) how to

1. Look into your browser's source code
2. Locate any CSS embed instructions
3. Utilize your inspector's "Net" tab to verify whether the style sheet has been loaded successfully

etc. etc.?

It is very tiring (not to mention excruciatingly boring) to do one-on-one support for this every time.

Current example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279709)

Comment: You'd have to cover a lot of browsers, especially since different versions of the same browser have completely different inspectors.

Comment: @Asad true. I could live with instructions for one specific platform though - a web dev can be expected to download and install a new browser